# JavaScript não funciona

Tags: javascript, data

Por quê esse meu código JavaScript não está dando certo? Meus outros códigos sempre funcionam, mas esse não tem reza que faça funcionar. Quero colocar um relógio com data na parte de cima da página e não quero deixar essas linhas de código dentro do index.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">

var now = new Date();
var mName = now.getMonth() +1 ;
var dName = now.getDay() +1;
var dayNr = now.getDate();
var yearNr=now.getYear();
if(dName==1) {Day = "Domingo";}
if(dName==2) {Day = "Segunda-feira";}
if(dName==3) {Day = "Terça-feira";}
if(dName==4) {Day = "Quarta-feira";}
if(dName==5) {Day = "Quinta-feira";}
if(dName==6) {Day = "Sexta-feira";}
if(dName==7) {Day = "Sábado";}
if(mName==1){Month = "Janeiro";}
if(mName==2){Month = "Fevereiro";}
if(mName==3){Month = "Março";}
if(mName==4){Month = "Abril";}
if(mName==5){Month = "Maio";}
if(mName==6){Month = "Junho";}
if(mName==7){Month = "Julho";}
if(mName==8){Month = "Agosto";}
if(mName==9){Month = "Setembro";}
if(mName==10){Month = "Outubro";}
if(mName==11){Month = "Novembro";}
if(mName==12){Month = "Dezembro";}
if(yearNr < 2000) {Year = 1900 + yearNr;}
else {Year = yearNr;}
var todaysDate =(" " + Day + ", " + dayNr + "/" + Month + "/" + Year);

document.write('  '+todaysDate);

</SCRIPT>

<SPAN ID="Clock">00:00:00</SPAN>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    <!--
var Elem = document.getElementById("Clock");
function Horario(){
    var Hoje = new Date();
    var Horas = Hoje.getHours();
    if(Horas < 10){
        Horas = "0"+Horas;
    }
    var Minutos = Hoje.getMinutes();
    if(Minutos < 10){
        Minutos = "0"+Minutos;
    }
    var Segundos = Hoje.getSeconds();
    if(Segundos < 10){
        Segundos = "0"+Segundos;
    }
    Elem.innerHTML = Horas+":"+Minutos+":"+Segundos;
}
window.setInterval("Horario()",1000);
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Se não quer deixar o código na *index*, onde deseja colocá-lo? Em um arquivo JavaScript separado? E por quê diz que não funcionou? Deu algum erro? Qual?

Comment: Quero usar ele no javascript separado. Quando coloco desse jeito ai no js, ele aparece erro falando que esta faltando uma declaração e no começo fala que espera uma nova linha ou om ponto-e-virgula. Quero chamar essa função do javascript pelo index para que apareça no top da página html

Comment: Tem um `<!--` dentro da tag de `<script>` que faz com que não funcione. Agora dá para fazer tudo isso bem mais organizado e curto

Comment: Ah sim Isac, eu tirei esse <!-- mas mesmo assim deu erro. Como seria mais curto e organizado. Achei alguns aqui, mas quando jogo pro html, ele não puxa formatação que eu quero e também muito extenso.

Answer (score 1):

Para que o seu código funcione tem apenas de retirar o `<!--` que está no segundo `<script>`:

```html
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">

var now = new Date();
var mName = now.getMonth() +1 ;
var dName = now.getDay() +1;
var dayNr = now.getDate();
var yearNr=now.getYear();
if(dName==1) {Day = "Domingo";}
if(dName==2) {Day = "Segunda-feira";}
if(dName==3) {Day = "Terça-feira";}
if(dName==4) {Day = "Quarta-feira";}
if(dName==5) {Day = "Quinta-feira";}
if(dName==6) {Day = "Sexta-feira";}
if(dName==7) {Day = "Sábado";}
if(mName==1){Month = "Janeiro";}
if(mName==2){Month = "Fevereiro";}
if(mName==3){Month = "Março";}
if(mName==4){Month = "Abril";}
if(mName==5){Month = "Maio";}
if(mName==6){Month = "Junho";}
if(mName==7){Month = "Julho";}
if(mName==8){Month = "Agosto";}
if(mName==9){Month = "Setembro";}
if(mName==10){Month = "Outubro";}
if(mName==11){Month = "Novembro";}
if(mName==12){Month = "Dezembro";}
if(yearNr < 2000) {Year = 1900 + yearNr;}
else {Year = yearNr;}
var todaysDate =(" " + Day + ", " + dayNr + "/" + Month + "/" + Year);

document.write('  '+todaysDate);

</SCRIPT>

<SPAN ID="Clock">00:00:00</SPAN>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
//   <!--
var Elem = document.getElementById("Clock");
function Horario(){
    var Hoje = new Date();
    var Horas = Hoje.getHours();
    if(Horas < 10){
        Horas = "0"+Horas;
    }
    var Minutos = Hoje.getMinutes();
    if(Minutos < 10){
        Minutos = "0"+Minutos;
    }
    var Segundos = Hoje.getSeconds();
    if(Segundos < 10){
        Segundos = "0"+Segundos;
    }
    Elem.innerHTML = Horas+":"+Minutos+":"+Segundos;
}
window.setInterval("Horario()",1000);
</SCRIPT>
```

Repare que do código que tem na pergunta apenas comentei o `<!--`.

Dá no entanto para fazer o que está a tentar fazer de uma forma bem mais organizada, flexível e curta:

```js
var now = new Date();
var mName = now.getMonth();
var dName = now.getDay() +1;
var dayNr = now.getDate();
var yearNr = now.getFullYear(); //troca de getYear() para getFullYear()

const weekDays = ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira','Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado' ];
const monthNames = ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'];

let day = weekDays[dName-1]; //obter o dia da semana com base no array
let month = monthNames[mName]; //obter o nome do mês com base no array
let todaysDate = " " + day + ", " + dayNr + "/" + month + "/" + yearNr;
document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = todaysDate;

const elem = document.getElementById("clock");

setInterval(function(){
    let hoje = new Date();     
    elem.innerHTML = hoje.getHours().toString().padStart(2,"0")+":"+
                     hoje.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2,"0")+":"+
                     hoje.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2,"0");
},1000);
```

```html
<span id="today"></span>
<span id="clock">00:00:00</span>
```

Resumo das alterações:

- É desaconselhado o uso etiquetas e/ou atributos em maiúsculas por isso troquei grande parte delas
- `document.write` é desaconselhado e por isso criei um novo `<span>` para colocar a data no formato que tinha
- Criei um array para os dias da semana e outro para os meses para ficar organizado e mais simples
- Fiz a lógica dos zeros no relógio com base na função [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) da string que facilita bastante
- Troquei o `getYear` por `getFullYear` que já trás o ano em 4 dígitos, não necessitando manipulação

Ainda daria para elaborar mais um pouco, mas pelo menos assim já lhe mostra outra forma de fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Sugeria colocar a função `Horario()` dentro do `setInterval`. Enxugaria mais o código. +1

Comment: @ÐvÐ Certo, concordo, fica ainda mais simples. E agradeço o comentário

Comment: Me tira uma dúvida, por favor, esse padStart funciona em todos os navegadores?

Comment: @ÐvÐ Pela própria [documentação no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), apenas não funciona no IE antigo, mesmo no Edge funciona. Ainda assim eles tem o Polyfill caso não esteja disponível.

Comment: No IE 11 não funciona, no Edge funciona mesmo.

Comment: Desculpa minha ignorancia Isac, mas como faço pra colocar isso dentro da função ou dentro de um arquivo javascript pra fazer a chamada pelo html?

Comment: @FábioAlves Basta incluir o arquivo de javascript com `<script src="arquivo.js"></script>` no `<head>` do html e colocar o código todo no arquivo dentro de `window.onload = function {/*codigo da pergunta aqui */};`